# How do I filter Azure Storage Table using OData Filter on unique Lastname in LogicApps?

Tags: azure, odata, azure-logic-apps, power-automate, azure-logic-app-standard

I would like to filter on unique / distinct Lastname while using the Get Entities from the Azure Storage Table. Distinct is currently not supported and groupby also doesn't seem to fit. How can I filter on unique Lastname using the OData Filter?

Answer (score 2):

At a moment there is no option to query directly with unique or distinct keywords. You can refer to this [Official Documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service#unsupported-query-operators) for more information.

[image]

You can give feedback [HERE](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/905242-update-management) for a Feature request.